# I want to sum a column till a negative value is reached, then start sum all over again in Google BQ

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

| ID | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 1 |
| abc | 1 |
| abc | -1 |
| abc | -1 |
| xyz | 1 |
| xyz | -1 |

output:

| ID | sum(quantity) |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 2 |
| xyz | 1 |

Comment: Is the quantity always +/- 1?  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets and your question seems to pre-suppose an ordering.  How is that determined?

Answer (score -1):

Based on the expected output you shared, it seems as if you are only summing positive values. You may try the following approach.

```sql
SELECT
     ID,
     SUM(
         CASE
             WHEN quantity > 0 THEN quantity 
             ELSE 0 
         END
     )
FROM
    my_table
GROUP BY
    ID
```

Let me know if this works for you. If not please provide more sample data and results.